# How am I supposed to win the last fight?

Tags: shadowrun-returns

I'm playing the Nightmare Harvest mod and I'm at the point where I'm facing about 20 lonestar members by myself.  I've been "boosted" by the dragon, so I have a bit more hp and 5 ap per turn, but there's still no way I can tackle all 20 of them.  How am I supposed to win the fight?

I'm specced as a street samurai with mostly rifle and some adept skills if that matters.